# Can`t construct right data format when use Html5 fetch and FormData

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-data, fetch-api

I just try to use fetch to send a post to service, but the Form Data format is wrong, what should i do? Picture shows the detail problem of mine

[image]

Only you can save me , thank you!

Comment: Please post code as text, not screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `Content-Type` header and let fetch to set it automatically.

The problem is that `Content-Type` is wrong as it does not set the boundary to separate data so your server does not know how to parse the body.